# Why the Matlab grader returns that "Variable y has an incorrect value." when I have correct values returned from the constructor in testing?

Tags: matlab, constructor

I have a little problem with the returned results from the MATLAB homework. bo

The Question is to creat a constructor function called **SetTimeConstruct** to construct
the structure called **TimeHrMin** with 2 fields: **hoursVal** and **minutesVal** for the integer inputs of hours and minutes.

The constructor would check if the 0 <= **hoursVal** <= 24 and 0 <= **minutesVal** <= 60 when returns 0 for the value if not.

Example provided by the textbook is :

```
>>> time1 = SetTimeConstruct(23, 31)
time1 = 

  struct with fields:

      hoursVal: 23
    minutesVal: 31

>>> time2 = SetTimeConstruct(25, 31)
time2 = 

  struct with fields:

      hoursVal:0
    minutesVal: 31

>>> time3 = SetTimeConstruct(25, -1)
time3 = 

  struct with fields:

      hoursVal:0
    minutesVal: 0
```

And here's my code:

```
function TimeHrMin = SetTimeConstruct( hoursVal, minutesVal)

    % Your code goes here %
    if nargin == 2
        TimeHrMin.hoursVal = hoursVal
        TimeHrMin.minutesVal = minutesVal
        if (hoursVal > 24 | hoursVal < 0)
            TimeHrMin.hoursVal = 0
        end 
        if (minutesVal > 60 | minutesVal < 0)
            TimeHrMin.minutesVal = 0
        end
    else
        disp("Error with wrong number of arguments passing to the function")
        TimeHrMin.hoursVal = 0
        TImeHrMin.minutesVal = 0
    end
end
```

Testing Result:

```
>>> time1 = SetTimeConstruct(23, 31)
time1 = 

  struct with fields:

      hoursVal: 23
    minutesVal: 31

>>> time1 = SetTimeConstruct(-1, -1)
time1 = 

  struct with fields:

      hoursVal: 0
    minutesVal: 0
```

These results should be matched with the expectations, but the matlab grader says that
*"Variable y has an incorrect value."*.
So I'm little confused by this information and it might be an error in my code.

Please check my code and if the testing values are valid, thanks!

Comment: You're certain it's not 0 <= hoursVal < 24 and 0 <= minutesVal < 60, correct?

Comment: @QuaternionsRock Yes I'm certain that )<= hoursVal <= 24 and 0<= minutesVal <= 60

Comment: `0 <= hoursVal <= 24` makes no sense. There's not 25 hours in a day. Likewise with `0 <= minutesVal <= 60`. Also, `SetTimeConstruct(5,434)` would return 5:0 instead of 0:0.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, but this is the questions' wordings. Also, SetTimeConstruct(5, -1) should return 5:0 for any input that is not in the range.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I now tries for the `0<= hoursVal < 24` and same as `0<= minutesVal <60` but the results still shows  "Variable y has an incorrect value."

Comment: You said “The constructor would check if the 0 <= hoursVal <= 24 **and** 0 <= minutesVal <= 60 when returns 0 for the value if not.” This means that if hours is outside the proper range, no matter what the minutes do, the output has to be 0. Do you get to see what the input are when the function fails? Maybe it gets arrays as input?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you for this advice! The constructor returns 0 for the input of minutes `or ` hours if they have wrong value respectively, so if I have (25, 13), it returns (0, 13), and if both wrong like (25, -1), it returns (0, 0). I think I need to pay attention for the conditions of inputs.